# How to check system time in Wherigo (Urwigo)

Tags: lua, urwigo, wherigo

I'm using Urwigo to create Wherigo cartridge.

I'm using LUA snippets, in which I'd like to utilize the system time, however, I can't find out, how to get it?

If there's such option, will it be time returned by device (Android) or GPS system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the Urwigo/Wherigo API supports the lua standard libraries. You can use the [`os.date` function](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-os.date) available in the `os` library.

The time returned will be the device system's time.